# Aligning Text in CSS

Tags: html, css

It's easy to align text in css! by using text-align:center;
but I Just make this

```
.readmore {
    width: 80px;
    height: 30px;
    background: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 3px;
    float: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Rambla', sans-serif;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 1s;
    -o-transition: background-color 1s;
    -moz-transition: background-color 1s;
    transition: background-color 1s;
}

.readmore:hover {
    background-color: #F79100;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #000;
    font-family: 'Rambla', sans-serif;
}
```

And On HTML

```
<div id="readmore">Read More</div>
```

My Question is That When I see the button, the text inside it (READ MORE) was not perfectly aligned in center from top - left - right - bottom. How can i do it! ?

Comment: Please provide a fiddler for this.

Comment: You gave your div an id. Ids are refered to with `#` in css, `.` is for classes.

Comment: @user2948424 So, do you want to center the box (relatively to the window, document, its parent, ...) or do you want to center box's text relatively to the box?

Comment: @arkascha http://jsfiddle.net/nB6P6/

Comment: @MarcelGwerder Thanks! :) 
Oriol i want to center box's text relatively to the box. But problem solved. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you use `id="readmore"` attribute but your CSS is `.readmore`. Instead, use one of these

- `id="readmore"` and `#readmore`
- `class="readmore"` and `.readmore`

To center the box horizontally (relatively to its parent), you could use

```
.readmore {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Yr6Ge/)

Moreover, if you want to center button's text vertically (relatively to the box), use

```
.readmore {
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px; /* same as height */
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Yr6Ge/1/)

Comment: hmm ok Thanks, I will now use ID :D, I make some changes in my question, you can see again

Comment: hmm Done, Thanks once again :)

Answer (score 1):

`margin-left: auto;` and
`margin-right: auto;`
Should center align the div id box you have made :)

Oh, and also, you should use # instead of . when it comes to ID's.
The dots are for classes.

**Vertically AND Horizontal alignment:**

You can use the following to vertically align the div
Just make sure you assign width and height with % aswell and remove the width of the element from the left percentage, do the same thing with the height.

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;`
```

Comment: `margin:0 auto` for simplicity.

Comment: Yes, another possibility :)

Comment: hmmm Yea , It Centers. But sorry i forgot to mention in the question that i also want it to come in center. Equal margins from top - left - bottom - right!
AS you said margin-left: auto; margin-right:auto; 
I tried margin-top: auto; margin-bottom:auto; But didn't work :|

Comment: making it vertically centered introduces another problem. It really depends on what you wish to vertically center...

Comment: I added an alternative method of aligning elements vertically

Answer (score 1):

In your css, change `.readmore` to `#readmore`.

The `.` prefix refer to a class name, while the `#` prefix refer to id.

Basically, use `.class` and `#Id`.